# Shortcut to create a method stub in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I think some shortcut to create a method stub in eclipse might be useful. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Another way to create a method stub is through Ctrl+1 option.

Comment: I really do love CTRL + 1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Type `public_method` (see Java/Editor/Templates in preferences for more options) or method name and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, and would you by any chance know of other shortcuts that could be helpful when trying TDD?

Comment: Nope. I do not have a project where I can try TDD because they have custom UI components, run inside large framework, use heuristic, numerical or impossible-to-calculate-by-hand algorithms what makes them impossible to test.

Comment: by typing method name and press ctrl+space, how can we change the default method code from private to public?

Comment: Or just type `pu` as Alexander has pointed out in an other answer.

Comment: @hetaoblog Please press `Ask Question` in the top right corner

Answer (score 9):

In Addtion to the accepted answer:
Typing `pu` for a public method (with `returntype` and `name`)is enough:

Type `pu` and then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and then  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

Type your method name and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Also worth noting is, type 'test' and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and it will give you the option to create a test method stub.

Answer (score 4):

How about loking to this link  [eclipse ref doc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-refactor.htm)?

It says that :  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>" will do , plus many others.

Comment: This shortcut is not for creating a method stub, instead it gives you the possibilty of extracting a piece of code in a new method, so you should select code then hit the combination.

Answer (score 2):

If you press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>S</kbd>. 
There comes a dropdown, then select the override/implement methods, from there you can setup and implement the method in the prefered way.

Answer (score 1):

One other shortcut to create a method stub is ALT+SHIFT+M. 
source: 
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-refactor.htm

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

(<kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> on Mac)

If no superclass method exists to copy and you typed something like "myClass.newMethod(myInt, myEmployee)", Eclipse can generate newMethod in myClass using the types of the arguments provided.