# eclipse shortcut for creating a method that is not defined yet

Tags: java, eclipse

A quick question.

when I write my code I first create the structures, (using methods that are not yet implemented)
obviously at this point I get errors. but then I go back and start creating the method. 
There is a `short cut with mouse` that if you hover over the method it pops some `options` and one of them lets you to `create the method` with some `default` return value,

So my question is is there a `keyboard short cut` that lets me create that specific method just like when I create it with mouse short cut (not all of them)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521940/shortcut-to-create-a-method-stub-in-eclipse

Comment: @DanielStanley I had checked that answer before, but it wasn't working for me, [ctrl + space] just doesn't work

Comment: In Eclipse look 'window > preferences > general > key" part. You must see the "Content Assist (Ctrl + Space)". If it is different you can restore command. Also  in “Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced“. Make sure “Other Java Proposals” is ticked.

Answer (score 0):

Please write a method's name like `example()` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.